# How to create a binary column a timedelta and a list of bins

Tags: python, list, date, binary

I am looking to create a binary column from a list and a timedelta. Here is what I have so far:

```
weather_list = ['5', '15', '30', '40'}
for i in weather_list:
    col = 'r_' + i
    epi.data[col] = np.where((help.data['help_beg_date'] + timedelta(float(i) -
                                                                 1)) >= help.data['HL_DATE'], 1, 0)
```

However, the output to this is cumulative. For example; if an observation is 16 days from the `help_beg_dt`, it will return it's values from columns `r_5`, `r_15`, and `r_30` as 0, 1, 1, 1. I need the output column values to be 0, 1, 0, 0. The 1 value being under `r_30` but over r_15.

I am thinking of creating another list which would attain the next sequence of i; so I can use a greater and lesser than expression. I am assuming you could possibly do this with just the one list.

Comment: Would you please add your whole code here? The question is still vague!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to me a variation on 'binning' a column based on a list of windows. This is usually achieved by `pd.cut`. For you the series that you are binning is

```
datediff = help.data['HL_DATE'] - help.data['help_beg_date']
```

and you wish to bin this according to weather list. First we need to convert these timedeltas to days; this is accecced through the `dt.days` method of the series (`dt` is short for datetime). Then we can use `pd.cut` to construct the bins like this (note I have added 0 into the weather list, to make valid windows):

```
weather_list = [0, 5, 15, 30, 40]
bins = pd.cut(datediff.dt.days, weather_list)
bins
0      (0, 5]
1     (5, 15]
2    (15, 30]
3    (15, 30]
dtype: category
Categories (4, object): [(0, 5] < (5, 15] < (15, 30] < (30, 40]]
```

Finally this can be converted to indicator columns with `pd.get_dummies`:

```
indicators = pd.get_dummies(bins)
indicators

   (0, 5]  (5, 15]  (15, 30]  (30, 40]
0       1        0         0         0
1       0        1         0         0
2       0        0         1         0
3       0        0         1         0
```

And you can add these to your dataframe using

```
pd.concat([epi.data,indicators],axis = 1)
```